# replacingOccurrences error

Tags: ios, swift, string, swift2

From udacity course I am trying below code

```
 let password = "Meet me in St. Louis"
 let newPassword = password.replacingOccurrences(of: "e", with: "3")
```

This is giving

```
Playground execution failed: Introduction.xcplaygroundpage:31:19: error: value of type 'String' has no member 'replacingOccurrences'
let newPassword = password.replacingOccurrences(of: "e", with: "3")
              ^~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Forcefully I have to use

```
let password = "Meet me in St. Louis"
let newPassword = password.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("me", withString: "ss")
```

Any clue why this error coming? I am using swift version 2.2

Comment: let newPassword = password.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("e",withString:"3") for Swift 2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string.replacingOccurrences(of: "word", with: "newWord")` is a swift 3 API so its correct that playground giving a error: value of type `'String'` has no member `'replacingOccurrences'`.

Try the same code in Xcode 8 and above it should work fine.

Answer (score 11):

In case you run this code example from the command line (by running Swift REPL), add `import Foundation` at the beginning of your .swift file.

Comment: Also writing it in an empty Playground needs the same import

Comment: I just executed `import Foundation` in the REPL and that worked as well.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you have Swift version 3+

Also, make sure that you :

```
 import Foundation
```

Answer (score 1):

I also took that course on Udacity. It is set up for Swift 3 and Xcode 8. Make sure you are running the latest version of Xcode and try it again.